# Install Go 1.20 from source and mark as Build-Depends in debian/control file?

Tags: go, build, debian, apt, deb

I build my Go service into binary and then pack into .deb file. Go version is 1.20

However currently Go 1.20 is not supported by Ubuntu 22.04 apt repository.

And therefore using debian/control for the service:

`Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 11), dh-exec, dh-python, dh-systemd, go (>= 1.20)`

Will result in:

`dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: go (>= 1.20)`

Go is installed at `/usr/lib/go-1.20`

My question is how can I install Go 1.20 from source `and` being able to refer to the exact `go (>= 1.20)` Go version in the `debian/control` file?

Comment: You do not have to have Go installed to run your program.

Comment: @Peter please notice, that I only refer to Build-Depends, not Depends :)